# Type Alias in Agda

Tags: agda, type-alias

In Haskell, types can be defined to be an alias for another type. For example, I could write

```hs
type MString = Maybe String
```

Is it possible to have aliases like this in Agda, too? I only know of the `data` keyword that forces me to write a new wrapper data type with named constructors:

```
data MString : Set where
  mstring : Maybe String → MString
```

where I would just like to write

```
data MString = Maybe String
```

just as in Haskell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just write

```
MString : Set
MString = Maybe String
```

without any `type` or `data` keyword (the `MString : Set` annotation is optional in this case but recommended).

Comment: I see. Thank you! This notation makes sense, just define the type as a constant. :)